# Alternate interior angles with two crossing transversals

Tags: geometry

Consider the following diagram. There are two parallel lines with two transversals which cross at arbitrary angles (ignore any symmetry in the drawing).

[image]

From the "alternate interior angles" theorem, we can conclude that 1 = 2, 3 = 4, 5 = 6, and 7 = 8 by considering each transversal separately. However, can we say something about pairs of angles formed by different transversals? For example, can we say that 6 = 1 and 2 = 5? Intuitively, it makes sense, but I'm having a hard time proving it.

Comment: If they are "arbitrary angles", then no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

does it make sense now? just consider the angles more arbitrary than the diagram you made